# What is the significance of the different words Paul uses to describe death, dead, and being put to death when writing about sin and the law?

Tags: greek, romans, law, sin, death

Throughout Romans, Paul writes about the dead, death, and  being put to death. A few examples, resurrection from the dead (1:4), being dead to sin (6:2), and raised from the dead (4:24). But he uses different words: ἀποθνῄσκω [[G599-*apothnēskō*]](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G599&t=KJV), θάνατος [[G2288-*thanatos*]](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G2288&t=KJV), and νεκρός [[G3498-*nekros*]](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G3498&t=KJV).

Three are found in one verse:

> We know that Christ, being raised from the dead (νεκρῶν), will never die (ἀποθνῄσκει) again; death (θάνατος) no longer has dominion over him. (6:9) [ESV]

When writing about being dead to sin, dead to the law, and sin being dead without the law, Paul also uses all three:

> By no means! How can we who died (ἀπεθάνομεν) to sin still live in it? (6:2)
>
> Likewise, my brothers, you also have died (ἐθανατώθητε)<sup>1</sup> to the law through the body of Christ, so that you may belong to another, to him who has been raised from the dead (νεκρῶν), in order that we may bear fruit for God. (7:4)
>
> But sin, seizing an opportunity through the commandment, produced in me all kinds of covetousness. For apart from the law, sin lies dead (νεκρά). (7:8)

All mean “dead” so what exactly is Paul trying to get across by using different words?

<sub>1. ἐθανατώθητε is the verb of θάνατος</sub>

Comment: *What is the significance ?* - There is no significance. It's like asking “why is the common Greek word for *death* unrelated to the common Greek word for *corpse* ?” Which, in itself, is like asking “why are the common English words for *hand* and *foot* unrelated to the common English words for *gloves* and *socks* ?” At any rate, the question belongs on a [different](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: @Lucian Textual critics see significance in word choice. One way to understand a writers choice of different words is to examine them within the various contexts the writer employs them. IMO this is hermenuetics.

Comment: What choice ? The Greek language was not invented by Saint Paul.

Comment: @RevelationLad  There is significance in the word choices, they are, after all, God's words, like pure silver refined seven times, but then hermeneutics is not about God, but a particular approach to trying to understand the text. I personally believe, as ScottS says, "the Bible is verbally, plenary inspired by God, so every word matters," so when someone else says, "there is no significance," just take it with a grain of sand, and ask them to "show their work"  ... https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/466/why-should-one-participate-in-the-biblical-herme

Answer (score 1):

νεκρός is usually used in the Greek Scriptures and in Greek literature to mean essentially a corpse - a dead (lifeless) body.  Examples with νεκρός:

Genesis 23:4 LXX (Brenton)

> *I am a sojourner and a stranger among you, give me therefore possession of a burying-place among you, and I will bury my dead away from me.*

Luke 7:15 (KJV)

> *And he that was dead sat up, and began to speak*

Phrases relating to someone being raised from the dead (e.g. Romans 6:9) literally refer to one being raised *from the dead ones*: ἐκ νεκρῶν; where νεκρῶν is the genitive plural of νεκρός.

---

θάνατος and the related verbs ἀποθνῄσκω (or sometimes simply θνῄσκω) are the words for *death* and *to die*, respectively.  Death - θάνατος - can be contrasted with contrasted with ἀ-θανασία (*athanasia*), meaning immortality.  Forms of ἀποθνῄσκω and the related verb θνῄσκω are often translated as "dead" in some versions:

Matthew 9:24 (KJV)

> *For the maid is not dead* (οὐ γὰρ ἀπέθανε τὸ κοράσιον): lit. "... the maid did not die"

John 11:39

> *Then they took away the stone from the place where the dead was laid* (ἦραν οὖν τὸν λίθον οὗ ἦν ὁ τεθνηκὼς κείμενος) :  lit. "... where the having-died [one] was laid"

---

I think what might be odd to us is that νεκρός doesn't seem to be etymologically related to ἀποθνῄσκω or θνῄσκω and it isn't really tied to any verb.  It seems, though, that when a passage is describing the death of a specific person, perhaps in the context of their just having died, then a form of ἀποθνῄσκω or θνῄσκω appears.  When dead persons in general are being described, then νεκρός appears.

Comment: What is the difference In terms of being dead to sin or the law? Is there a natural comparison Paul is following?

Comment: Which verse do you have in mind re being dead to the law?

Comment: 7:8 apart from the law sin is dead

Answer (score 1):

"Christ was raised out from the deaths" (genitive plural of nekros) relates to the two deaths:

1. He died a spiritual 'substitutionary death' i.e. separation from God the Father when the sins of the world were imputed to Him while on the Cross, and while He received the punishment for those sins in our place (hence "substitutionary").
2. He died a physical death when He released His soul and spirit from His body.

For more info order (for free) the book "The Blood of Christ" from R.B.Thieme Jr., Bible Ministries, or "King of Kings, Lord of Lords" - both explain this concept.

Comment: Hi Tim, welcome to the site. Could you add any scriptural references or page numbers to Thieme's work to document your answer? Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour), and thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 0):

Studying this myself, but if your key passage is correct, "We know that Christ, being raised from the dead (νεκρῶν), will never die (ἀποθνῄσκει) again; death (θάνατος) no longer has dominion over him. (6:9), νεκρῶν is a noun plural, male, genitive. It refers to all those who are dead, who are corpses. ἀποθνῄσκει is a verb. Noun and corresponding verb need not have same root. θάνατος refers to a personified state, the state of being dead. It is at least indirectly related to its verb, ἀποθνῄσκει. It is the state of someone who has died, even if there is no corpse. That would be the difference between those three.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Comment: Hi Charles, welcome to the site! This looks like the start of a great answer--could you expand on how this directly answers the original question? Thanks for contributing!

Answer (score -1):

Paul is referring back to Genesis 2:17 from Hebrew -

> **בְּי֛וֹם אֲכָלְךָ֥ מִמֶּ֖נּוּ מ֥וֹת תָּמֽוּת**. Here, there are two deaths as referenced in Revelation 20:12-15 and other places. This is due to the consequences of eating from the Etz hada'at tov v'ra - the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, which is the Law of sin and death.

- Avi ben Moredechai
  www.cominghome.co.il

Comment: Welcome to BHSE! Make sure you take our Tour (lower left). Thanks